# $f(x)\geq 0\iff g(x)\geq 0$ and $g$ is strictly increasing

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be strictly increasing in all arguments. $\{x:f(x)\geq0\}$ is a closed set.

> Is it possible to construct a **continuous** $g$, strictly increasing in all arguments, such that $f(x)\geq 0\iff g(x)\ge0$, (possibly with some additional assumptions)?

I think a distance function will do the trick but I am not sure how to prove it.

Informally, because $f$ is strictly increasing, the boundary set $\{x:f(x)=0\}$ must be a curve with "negative slope" everywhere. Then the distance function $d\big(x,f^{-1}\big((-\infty,0]\big)\big)$ should be strictly increasing in all arguments when $d>0$.

Comment: why not taking $f=g$?

Comment: @daw I made  a mistake. $g$ is continuous, while $f$ is not.

Comment: This is somewhat imprecise, what do you mean by f nonnegative if and only if g is nonnegative. What should be the domain of g?

Comment: @JonathanHole Domain and variable added.

Comment: The distance function idea sounds good. Are you having trouble formalizing a definition of $g$ or stuck proving something about it?

Comment: @Karl I don't know how to prove that the distance function is increasing in all arguments.

Comment: Hmm yeah. What if you choose a notion of distance so that the level sets of $g$ have the same shape as the zero set of $f$?

Comment: @Karl I think your suggestion will do the trick but I am not sure how to choose this distance function...

Comment: @dodo you say that f is discontinuous. Can you edit the question to add the points/region of discontinuity + type of discontinuity?

Comment: @insipidintegrator $f$ is an $\textbf{arbitrary}$ function such that 1) strictly increasing and 2) $\{x:f(x)\geq 0\}$ is a closed set. If $f$ is continuous, we just take $f=g$. So we only consider the case where $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Hint: measure distance in a single fixed direction.

Comment: @Karl Like in the direction of $(1,1)$?

Comment: Yeah or $(1,0)$. I haven't worked out the details, but that should give level sets of $g$ that are congruent to the zero set of $f$, which should help relate the monotonicity of $f$ and $g$..

Comment: @Karl  I think your distance function, $D(x,A)=\inf\{d:x−(d,0)∈A\}$ (when $f(x)>0$), is much easier to be proved than mine. However I cannot find a proper reference for these types of "directional distance". Are you an economist by any chance?